# My android program cannot resolve any imports

Tags: android, import, compilation

[image]

As one can see my application crashes on start, because it cannot compile. But the reason for not being able to compile is that somehow NOTHING can be resolved to a type.

Comment: Check if Android library is included in build path. Also, see if problem persists after clean and rebuild.

Comment: @Marius seems like i had to clean and rebuild it yea. I've been having a problem with the R.java file dissappearing in other projects so i didn't even want to try to clean it :) - THANK YOU!!